# facebook graph api search doesn't return all checkins

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

There are some people who their checkins cannot be seen through the 'checkins' of the graph api, and neither through the search?q=checkins

Those people's checkins will only be published in their /fbid/feed as type 'status'
but if i want to get their checkins with all my friends as i do in the 'search' function, i cannot.

I have all the permissions with the access key..

Anyone else experienced this problem?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, the bugs that concern "some people", seemingly randomly, are about personal privacy settings. I had one such problem when querying if a user had liked my page : it worked for everyone whose likes where public but I needed user_likes for the others.

Hope it helps.

Comment: You're right.. It turns out there are privacy settings especially for apps. Thanks!!!